# How to get PowerPoint current slide index in Office Add-In API?

Tags: office365, office-addins, office-js

I'm developing an [Office Add-In](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs) for [Power Point](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/powerpoint/powerpoint-add-ins). An example from the documentation about [how to change slide](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/powerpoint/powerpoint-add-ins.md#navigate-to-a-particular-slide-in-the-presentation) is:

```
function goToSlideByIndex() {
    var goToNext = Office.Index.Next;

    Office.context.document.goToByIdAsync(goToNext, Office.GoToType.Index, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
            showMessage("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
        }
        else {
            showMessage("Navigation successful");
        }
    });
}
```

However, with this API I want to get the current slide id. Seems like there is no such a function in the [Office-JS API](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/master/reference/shared).

How do I get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the current index of active slide via using the **document.getSelectedDataAsync** method. Here is an example for your reference:

```
Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.SlideRange, function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
                app.showNotification("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
            }
            else {

                app.showNotification(asyncResult.value.slides[0].index);
            }
        });
```

Note, the function is an asynchronous method. The result maybe not expected when you change the slide quickly after you call this method

Comment: I saw this in the doc, but `document.getSelectedDataAsync` should return the current selected slides right?

Comment: `document.getSelectedDataAsync` return the selected data. And we also can use this method to get the index of current selected slides.

Comment: How about in slideshow mode? This method doesn't seem to be working in slideshow mode.